# Laptop fans always running even with 0% CPU usage

Tags: windows-7, bios, fan, cooling

Recently I noticed that my laptop's fans are always running (it didn't happen before). When I first turn on the laptop, fans run quite fast when BIOS step (common behavior) but the problem is that fans keep that speed always even when Windows 7 is started and doing nothing (no programs opened and 0% CPU usage). The expelled air is not hot and both two fans seem to run the same speed (CPU fan and GPU fan). These are the specs:

- MSI GS72 6QE-XES
- Windows 7 Professional
- Intel Core i7 6700HQ 2.6GHz
- 16GB RAM
- NVidia GTX970M 3GB
- Samsung SSD 128GB / HGST HDD 1TB

I bought it about 4 months ago so it hasn't excesive dust inside. I also checked the BIOS for options related with fans but couldn't find.

What is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is quite common for performance laptops to have the fans running 100% when on AC power, is that the case here? When on battery there are settings to allow or disallow this that could be in the OS or the BIOS.

Comment: @acejavelin Fans run the same with battery and AC power. I could find nothing by checking the BIOS. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: try to use speedfan to control the coolers: http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=5

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the reply. I already tried Speedfan but no fans are detected. Btw, I'm looking for the reason why this is happening and trying to fix it without third party software.

Comment: this is a BIOS/UEFI settings. Also try NoteBookFanControl: https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the Operating System a few times and test different options finally found the answer. In this particular case my laptop behaves de following way:

1. When I first turn on the laptop, all hardware components are on and running for the BIOS to check. I mean: sound card, touchpad, graphic cards etc... In most computers, fans are on at a considerable speed in this step.
2. When the Operating System is loaded, all the drivers control corresponding hardware components along with the software (programs), if appropiate.

Once again, in this case, my laptop is equipped with a nVidia GTX970M. The use of this graphical card means that the fans must be on in order to cool it. The problem came when drivers for this card weren't workiing properly or software didn't neither. Drivers control must regulate fans over this component and that was the problem.

3. Solution: update drivers, check that software setting for nVidia cards (in my case) are working properly and important too: check that there aren't startup programs that require the use of this graphical card (use of dedicated graphical card = fans usage).